# How do I add header above the column names?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

How do I add header above the column names? I was trying to add labels before and After from col no 2 to 4 and 5 to 7 respectively.

```
   data <- data.frame(Score = c("0-6","11-15","Total"),
                           Male = c(50,50,50),
                           Female = c(50, 50, 50),
                           total = c(100,100,100),
                           Male = c(50,50,50),
                           Female = c(50, 50, 50),
                           total = c(100,100,100))
library(kableExtra)



data  %>% 
  kable("pipe",
        col.names = c("Score", "Female", "Male", "Total", "Female", "Male", "Total" ),    align = c("lrrrrrr"),
        caption = "Score") %>% 
  add_header_above(header = c(" " = 1, "Before" = 3, "After" = 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply change the format from "pipe" to "html"?

```
data  %>% 
  kable(format = "html",
        col.names = c("Score", "Female", "Male", "Total", "Female", "Male", "Total" ),    align = c("lrrrrrr"),
        caption = "Score",) %>% 
  add_header_above(header = c(" " = 1, "Before" = 3, "After" = 3))
```

[image: Result]